# Java RGB to YCbCr conversion formula yields wrong results

Tags: java, colors, formula, rgb, color-space

I'm trying to convert an RGB image to YCbCr manually, but somehow, the results are off - I compared them to results from http://www.picturetopeople.org/color_converter.html, where you can input RGB values and it converts them to the respective YCbCr ones.
and they seem to yield random colors.

e.g. :

R: 71 G: 78 B: 36

results in:

Y: 71 Cb: 108 Cr: 127

while it should be

Y: 77 Cb: 111 Cr: 128

Sometimes the difference is also a lot bigger. This is my function:

```
public YCbCr[][] RGBtoYCbCr(BufferedImage img){

                YCbCr[][] ycrcbimg = new YCbCr[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];

                for(int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++){ 

                        Color pixel = new Color(img.getRGB(i,j));
                        int r = pixel.getRed();
                        int g = pixel.getGreen();
                        int b = pixel.getBlue();

                        int y  = (int)(0+ (0.299   * r) + (0.587   * g) + (0.114   * b));
                        int cb = (int)(128-(0.168736 * r) - (0.331264 * g) + (0.50000 * b));
                        int cr = (int)(128+ (0.50000 * r) - (0.418688 * g) - (0.081312 * b));   

                        ycrcbimg[i][j] = new YCbCr(y,cb,cr);

                    }                 
                }                                       

               return ycrcbimg;
            }
```

I used the formula my professor gave me.

Comment: Well, the page you linked to obviously used some other coefficients than the ITU-R BT.601 ones (0.299, 0.587, 0.114). But they don't say on the page what they used instead. I would suggest you use what the professor gave you.

Comment: You may check also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr where you find different methods for different uses. (So BT.601, BT.709, Jpeg). Remember that on video often just less range were used (16-235 or 16-240).

Comment: Additionally from the page you linked: "P2P uses a **modified** YCbCr model, with all 3 ranges between 0 and 255, and that can make all needed convertions." So this is the answer